# Accessing Google Keep data through script?

Tags: python, bash, google-api, google-keep

I am trying to create a script that get the data from a google keep list I was thinking [Google Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) might do part of what I want but I cannot find a API to automate the downloads. Does anyone know a way to grab this data via script (python/bash) so that I can easily extract what I need?

Answer (score 2):

In the meanwhile there is an API, see here: https://developers.google.com/keep/api/reference/rest

Also, there is a python library that implements this API (I'm *not* the author of the library): https://github.com/kiwiz/gkeepapi

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is allowed or not, but you could login via a BeautifulSoup session and navigate to the site you wish to parse.

I've written a quite similar script for Python, you can find it [at github](https://github.com/soultice/print-google-events/blob/master/src/Tasks.py), i thinkt it's pretty self-explanatory but if you should require any more help feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

You could use selenium library for that.
Used the framework to scrape the keep.google.com webpage for all the notes and export them to a csv file

This Might be helpful, i made the script to backup my notes to my computer
https://github.com/darshkpatel/GoogleKeep_Backup

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for Google Keep at this time.  I don't think your going to be able automate Google Takeout either the best you will be able to do would be run it manually then create your own application to import it were ever it is you want to import it to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an automated solution for this question: [a link](https://github.com/Dmitry9/exportKeep)!

Or just execute these commands in the terminal:

```
git clone https://github.com/Dmitry9/exportKeep.git;
cd exportKeep;
npm install;
npm run scrape;
```

After all dependencies installed  (could take a minute or so) chrome instance will navigate to the sign-in page. After posting credentials it will scroll to the bottom of the window to force the browser to load all of the notes inside DOM. Inspecting the output of the terminal you will find a path to the saved JSON file.